# Calculating an energy of an electron with known De Broglie wavelength (why can't we calculate it similar than we do it for a photon)

Tags: particle-physics, photons

Lets say we have an electron with known De Broglie wavelength $\lambda$. Can anyone justify or explain why we calculate its energy $E$ using **1st** the De Broglie relation $\lambda = h/p$ to get momentum $p$ and **2nd** using the invariant interval to calculate $E$:

\begin{align}
p^2c^2 &= E^2 - {E_0}^2\\
E &= \sqrt{p^2c^2 + {E_0}^2}
\end{align}

Why we are not alowed to do it like we do it for a photon:

\begin{align}
E=h\nu = h\frac{c}{\lambda}
\end{align}

These equations return different results.

Comment: Because of Pauli exclusion principle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the equation $E=h\nu$ does not account for the energy equivalent of particle's mass. It assumes zero mass.

Photons has zero mass. You can actually substitute zero for $E_0$ so that $p^2c^2 = E^2$, and then apply de Broglie's relations so that $E = h\nu$.

Comment: False. see [Matter waves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matter_wave)

Comment: Maybee it really has to do something with a fact that an electron has a mass...